# Как разделить всю карту Яндекс на участки по координатам

Tags: яндекс-карты

Есть задача получить более чем 10000 координат обьектов из базы данных и поставить для них метки на карте.

Нужен способ для получения координат `map.getBounds()` по частям, чтобы при зуме или перемещении карты в запросе на базу для получения координат новых обьектов отправить координаты только тех участков, данные которых пока не получены

Comment: Опишите сценарий чуть подробней, пожалуйста. В базе есть координаты или адреса? Вы собираетесь геокодировать объекты или границы карты? Если границы, то для чего? Решили ли какой метод для отображения результатов использовать? Добавление на карту такого количества объектов - тоже нетривиальная задача: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/many-objects-docpage/

Comment: В базе данных есть все координаты обьектов, нужно разделить видимую часть участка карты(координаты) на части, чтобы при перемещении или зума карты шел запрос только с теми участками, метки которых пока не добавились в карту

Comment: Если правильно вас понимаю, вы собираетесь реализовать свой аналог LoadingObjectManager от Яндекса? Почему не использовать предлагаемый ими вариант? Вы планируете каждый раз при смещении карты удалять все объекты с карты и добавлять через ObjectManager после ajax-запроса объекты из ближайшего окружения видимой области снова?

Comment: Не знал про этот метод, прочитал, все понятно.

Comment: Спасибо большое